# How to find the sum of digits using recursion in Java?

Tags: java

I need to create a program that will calculate the sum of the digits of the positive integer number. The user should input one positive integer number, and the program should display the sum of its digits. The output of the program should be:

```
Please input a positive integer number N: 2563

Sum of all digits of the number 2563 is: 16
```

I have done this correctly so far, however I am not sure how to recreate this program using recursion. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SumOfDigits {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int N = 0;
    int x = 0;
    int sum = 0;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("******");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer number N: ");

    N = keyboard.nextInt();

    int M = N;

    while(N > 0) {

        x = N % 10;

        sum = sum + x;

        N = N / 10;
    }


    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Sum of all digits of the number " + M + " is: " + sum);
    System.out.println();
    keyboard.close();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem with recursion, you have to break the problem to a smaller problem (or several smaller problems), and use the solution[s] of the smaller problem[s] to find the solution of the original problem.

In the case of sum of digits, the are several ways to break the problem.

The easiest one is probably to remove the last digit, solve the problem for the smaller number, and add the last digit to the sum of digits of the smaller number.

In pseudo code (I'll leave the actual coding to you), it would look like this:

```
sumOfDigits (x)
    if (x < 10)
        return x
    last = x % 10 // extract the last digit
    return last + sumOfDigits (x/10) // recursively find the sum of digits of the first n-1 
                                     // digits and add the last digit
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do this:

```
public static int sum(int num, int total) {
    if (num == 0) return total;

    total += num % 10;
    return sum(num / 10, total);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("total: " + sum(123456789, 0));
}
```

This computes a total of 45, which is correct.  The idea is that each recursive step, we add the tens digit to the running total, then pass that total along with the input number divided by ten.  The base case occurs when the input number is zero, indicating that there are no more digits remaining to be summed.

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
static int sum(int n) {  
    return n == 0 ? 0 : (n % 10 + sum_of_digit(n / 10));
}
```

Example input: 12345

```
12345 % 10 which is equal-to 5 + 
1234 % 10 which is equal-to 4 + 
123 % 10 which is equal-to 3 + 
12 % 10 which is equal-to 2 + 
1 % 10 which is equal-to 1 + 
0 return
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this function :

```
static int sumDigits(int no) 
{ 
        return no == 0 ? 0 : no%10 +  
                  sumDigits(no/10) ; 
}
```

Hope it helps!!